# Click on "this" in a backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

I am a newbie with backbone and i have a little problem with it events system.

I have a view who represents an li element, and i want to do something when i click on it.

Here is my code :

```
var IndicatorView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  className: 'indicator',
  initialize: function(options){
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, "controller"));
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    var self=this ;
    this.$el.on("click", function(){
      alert(self.model.get('name'));
    })
  },
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.model.get('name'));
    return this; // enable chained calls
  }
});
```

For the moment, it works, but using jQuery events. How can I do the same thing with backbone events ? Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an empty selector to bind an event to the view `el`:

```
var IndicatorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'indicator',

    events: {
        'click': function() {
            alert(this.model.get('name'));
        }
    },

    initialize: function(options){
        _.extend(this, _.pick(options, "controller"));

        // listenTo is recommended over on
        // http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
   },
   render: function(){
       this.$el.html(this.model.get('name'));
       return this; // enable chained calls
   }
});
```

See http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents for more info

Comment: It works, thanks a lot for the answer and for the piece of advice about listenTo :)